# Divide integers and print out the result as a float in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, type-conversion, mips, division, floating

I am working on an assignment that reads in integers and puts them into an array until a negative one is entered. I have to find the mean of the integers but the results must be printed out as a float. I've tried several ways of doing this but so far when i run it on QTSpim, the result says 'nan'.

Here is the portion of my code

```
mfc1 $t6, $f1 #t6 is the sum
cvt.s.w $f1, $f1 
mfc1 $t7, $f2 #t7 is the number of ints
cvt.s.w $f2, $f2  
div.s $f0, $f1, $f2
mov.s $f12, $f0
li $v0, 2
syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

`mfc1` is *Move Word From Floating Point* (`rt = fs`). You presumably want `mtc1` instead (`fs = rt`).

Comment: thank you for your answer, however, changing it from mfc1 to mtc1 still generates 'nan' when I run it

Comment: Well, I answered based on the code you've shown us. If you're still getting incorrect output then `$t6` and/or `$t7` do not contain what you expect them to. Use the single-step feature in QtSpim to step through your calculations until you find where either of these registers get an unexpected value.

Comment: I figured that posting the entire code would be a bit too much so i only included what was important, but maybe i should. $t6 and $t7 are right as well